# Error running Ant build task on remote Jenkins node

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins version 2.406 setup with a local controller node (using Java 11) and a remote agent setup to build apps.
I getting an error **The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect** when running the ant build task on the remote agent.

I have configured the "Ant" tool in remote agent after setting the same up in the controller.
This is what I am seeing in the console of the build

```
Started by upstream project "master" build number 61
originally caused by:
 Started by remote host 127.0.0.1
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
[EnvInject] - Preparing an environment for the build.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins system variables.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins build variables.
[EnvInject] - Injecting contributions.
Building remotely on agent_android in workspace C:\Java\Jenkins_Slave\.jenkins_android\workspace
Restoring workspace from build #61 of project retrieve_local
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C "C:\Java\Jenkins_Slave\apache-ant-1.10.13\bin\ant.bat -l basic_ant2.log && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
**The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have tried multiple things

- if I run the same ant task on the local node on the master everything works as expected and the ant task runs correctly
- if I run a Windows batch task running the same command as the ant task and that also works fine
- I have tried changing the ant tool configuration to use the "Default" ant but that fails in a different way
- I have gone back to a very simple Ant build.xml which just echos hello world in-case it was a task within the ant build file which was problematic

So I'm at a bit of a loss as to why it is failing.

[A screen capture of the failing build job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0zWA.png)

This is the XML of the failing build job

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
      <strategy class="hudson.tasks.LogRotator">
        <daysToKeep>-1</daysToKeep>
        <numToKeep>3</numToKeep>
        <artifactDaysToKeep>-1</artifactDaysToKeep>
        <artifactNumToKeep>1</artifactNumToKeep>
      </strategy>
    </jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
    <EnvInjectJobProperty plugin="envinject@2.901.v0038b_6471582">
      <info>
        <propertiesFilePath>$WORKSPACE/../../VersionInfo.txt</propertiesFilePath>
        <secureGroovyScript plugin="script-security@1244.ve463715a_f89c">
          <script></script>
          <sandbox>false</sandbox>
        </secureGroovyScript>
        <loadFilesFromMaster>false</loadFilesFromMaster>
      </info>
      <on>true</on>
      <keepJenkinsSystemVariables>true</keepJenkinsSystemVariables>
      <keepBuildVariables>true</keepBuildVariables>
      <overrideBuildParameters>false</overrideBuildParameters>
    </EnvInjectJobProperty>
  </properties>
  <scm class="hudson.plugins.cloneworkspace.CloneWorkspaceSCM" plugin="clone-workspace-scm@84.v147686859e1c">
    <parentJobName>retrieve_local</parentJobName>
    <criteria>Any</criteria>
  </scm>
  <assignedNode>agent_android</assignedNode>
  <canRoam>false</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <customWorkspace>workspace</customWorkspace>
  <builders>
    <hudson.tasks.Ant plugin="ant@487.vd79d090d4ea_e">
      <targets>custombuild -l build_android.log</targets>
      <antName>bundledAnt</antName>
      <buildFile>shell\platforms\android\build.xml</buildFile>
    </hudson.tasks.Ant>
  </builders>
  <publishers>
    <hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver>
      <artifacts>shell\platforms\android\bin\EdgeHybrid-release.apk, shell\platforms\android\bin\EdgeHybrid-release.aab, shell\platforms\android\build_android.log, resources\offline\html\js\cordova\cordova_plugins_android.js, cordovaPlugins.zip</artifacts>
      <allowEmptyArchive>false</allowEmptyArchive>
      <onlyIfSuccessful>false</onlyIfSuccessful>
      <fingerprint>false</fingerprint>
      <defaultExcludes>true</defaultExcludes>
      <caseSensitive>true</caseSensitive>
      <followSymlinks>true</followSymlinks>
    </hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver>
  </publishers>
  <buildWrappers>
    <EnvInjectBuildWrapper plugin="envinject@2.901.v0038b_6471582">
      <info>
        <propertiesFilePath>$WORKSPACE/build.conf</propertiesFilePath>
        <secureGroovyScript plugin="script-security@1244.ve463715a_f89c">
          <script></script>
          <sandbox>false</sandbox>
        </secureGroovyScript>
        <loadFilesFromMaster>false</loadFilesFromMaster>
      </info>
    </EnvInjectBuildWrapper>
    <hudson.plugins.build__timeout.BuildTimeoutWrapper plugin="build-timeout@1.30">
      <strategy class="hudson.plugins.build_timeout.impl.AbsoluteTimeOutStrategy">
        <timeoutMinutes>10</timeoutMinutes>
      </strategy>
      <operationList>
        <hudson.plugins.build__timeout.operations.AbortOperation/>
      </operationList>
    </hudson.plugins.build__timeout.BuildTimeoutWrapper>
  </buildWrappers>
</project>
```

TIA

Comment: Can you share some details on how the build job is configured ?

Comment: Hiya @carlverbiest thanks for the interest I've added an image of the failing build job and also the XML of the job, anything specific you were thinking of that I can explain rather than the complete job?